# How to export google drive file identifiers for all files in a directory

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a google drive directory with many files. In theory I could access them and cross-link them via 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/watch
or just using an URL with this identifier. The key issue is, how can I export the identifiers for the files in a google directory, doing this manually is not an option.

source:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/

Answer (score 0):

Export? I'm not sure I entirely understand what you mean by that, but I'm guessing you want a list of all the file IDs in a certain directory.

This is a simple case of using the [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) request. For 'q' you would want to do `'<folderID>' in parents` and for fields you would do `items/id,nextPageToken` (for efficiency). `items/id` gets you the file ID and `nextPageToken` is used to resend the list request to get the next set of IDs in the event it requires more than 1 page of results.

So, as an example, let's assume the folder you want is your root folder 'My Drive'. In that case, the following would be the query:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q='root'+in+parents&fields=items%2Fid%2CnextPageToken&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

and if nextPageToken comes back with something, you would subsequently do:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?pageToken={YOUR_PAGE_TOKEN}&q='root'+in+parents&fields=items%2Fid%2CnextPageToken&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```